# Ax 2012 r2 and r3 dixf client tools side by side

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

This is a question related to non-prod testing and evaluation

I know it's technically possible to have the Ax 2012 R2 client installed locally and have a copy of the R3 Client installation folder copied locally to allow a user to access both Ax 2012 R2 and R3 environments using the same machine

However, is it possible to do some kind of workaround like this to get the DIXF client tools for R3 working on the same local machine where the R2 DIXF client tools are already installed?

I can't just install the DIXF tools for R3 on the same machine as the installer complains about the older version of the DIXF client tools